# yasnippet color

Tags: org-mode, org-babel, yasnippet

I use yasnippet in orgmode to expand codeblocks of Python and start typing code.
My snippet is defined as:

```
# -*- mode: snippet -*-
# name: emacs-jupyter code block for python (silent)
# key: <spp
# --
#+BEGIN_SRC jupyter-python :session py :results silent output :async yes
$1
#+END_SRC
```

When I create the snippet and expand it, the cursor is positioned at the `$1` so I can start typing. Pressing `TAB` again positions the cursor after `#+END_SRC`.

**Problem**: After pressing `<spp TAB`, I can start typing, but `yasnippet` displays the text being typed in `green`, instead of using the colors for the Python language:
[image: 1]
The correct colors are only displayed after pressing `TAB` again to finish typing, or manually moving the cursor out of the code block:
[image: 2]

**Question**: How can I disable the green color `yasnippet` is using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably just change $1 to $0. That will just put the cursor there to start typing.

From the [documentation](https://joaotavora.github.io/yasnippet/snippet-development.html#org41a4ac7):

> Tab stops are fields that you can navigate back and forth by TAB and S-TAB. They are written by $ followed with a number. $0 has the special meaning of the exit point of a snippet. That is the last place to go when you've traveled all the fields.

Instead of using `$1`, using `$0` implies that after expanding the snippet (i.e., `<spp TAB`), the cursor will be placed at `$0`, which is the exit point of the snippet. When the cursor reaches the exit point, the green highlighting disappears.

Comment: Practical solution. Why does it work? Do you know where I can find the documentation that explains the use of `$`?

Comment: It is described here https://joaotavora.github.io/yasnippet/snippet-development.html in the template syntax section.

Comment: Thanks for helping! =D